# How to access entity functions with parameters in TWIG - symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, twig

I have a twig template in my Symfony2 project.
In the twig template, I have an entity object.
This entity object is linked to another entity with oneToMany relation.

Example:

```
{{ submission }} -> Submission entity
{{ submission.histories }} -> Histories entity -> I have here an array collection of histories
```

The entity histories has a field "state_to"

My goal is to get only the histories object where the state_to is 4

I tryed like that:

```
{{ submission.histories('status_to', 4)[0] }}
```

But this is not working.

I know that I can use:

```
{% for history in submission.histories %}
    {% if history.statusTo == 4 %}
        {{ history.statusDate|date("d F Y") }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I am allmost sure that there is a nicer way.

Comment: Well instead of fetching all your entites from the database and trying to filter them in your template ... you should create a repository method to fetch ONLY the ones having `history.statusTo = 4` and pass these to the template. Logic like this should not be included in a template.

Comment: Good idea @nifr, +1 for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a method `getHistoryByStatus($status)` in your entity to filter your histories based on the `status_to` field, then in your template:

```
{% set filtered_history = submission.historyByStatus(4)|default(false) %}
{% if filtered_history %}
    {{ filtered_history.statusDate|date("d F Y") }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: A method in the *entity* will still fetch all related histories ( as you will need to access `$this->getHistories()` inside this method which triggers doctrine to load the whole collection instead of only the related histories needed even with lazy loading enabled). Not a clean solution in this case. This belongs into a repository method to have the unneeded relations filtered out before getting the relations from database.

Comment: @nifr - that's no longer true.  You can now use [criteria](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) to filter.  Doing so will perform the filtering on the SQL level if the collection hasn't already been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

you could just find the histories object where the state_to is 4 within a method called in your controller. then pass it to the view. This method can be inside your controller, but is better to have it in your history repository maybe? or a manager..

try avoiding complexity in the views.